# (JIRA) Copy "component watcher" entries into list of "Watchers"

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I want to copy the list of users specified as *Component Watchers* (with the plugin of the same name) into the list of *Watchers*, at issue creation time. I'm trying to do this with a *Script-Runner* post-function, after creating a custom field of type *Component Watchers*.

The part that I'm missing is how to obtain the *Component Watchers* usernames as a list. Any idea?

Comment: I see that Component Watchers does not expose any API. Only chance is to contact author of Component Watchers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Behaviours plugin. There you can specify "behaviour"-s, that can be mapped to projects and issue types, and there you can specify Groovy Scripts to run during transitions.

It won't be easy, but it is versatile and does not eat too much resources.